# Why does this window show up as shorter than what was set?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am creating an app window like this:

```
var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;

//Create the app window
chrome.app.window.create(
    'test.html',
    {
        frame: "none",
        bounds:
        {
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
            top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
        },
        maxWidth: 700,
        maxHeight: 600,
        resizable: false,
        id: "test"
    }
);
```

but it shows on screen as only 591 pixels tall!

When I view the HTML/CSS in Chrome as a local HTML page, it shows as the proper height of 600 pixels tall. Why does creating it as a window make it 9 pixels too short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caching the size I had set the window to in a previous version and not allowing that to be changed via the `create` method. The only fix I found was to do:

```
function(myWin)
{
    myWin.moveTo( Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2), Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2) );
    myWin.resizeTo( 700, 600 );
}
```

in the callback for the `create` method

Comment: Or: a. Change the ID of the window; b. Manually clear the cached data from the Preferences file in the profile's directory.

Comment: If you don't want the window size to be cached, don't provide an ID (that is the ID's purpose).

Comment: Ben: the behavior is still annoying if you do want the window size to be cached but are trying to change the initial window size during development.

Comment: Don: sorry if that came off curtly, it wasn't intended that way. sowbug: Yes that's true. What I've done in this situation is change the ID as Vincent mentioned, then put it back before release. If you are creating a new version of your app with different constraints you have to give it a new ID.

Comment: @BenWells That's not correct behavior though. I want it to be a singleton but I should be able to change the size with the bounds settings (otherwise, what's the point of that?) The problem is not that it caches the behavior, but that it makes it unchangeable in create. And your suggestion of changing the ID in development unfortunately doesn't cover the use case where I've already released it but now am releasing a new update that changes the window size.

Comment: @VincentScheib I want it to be a singleton, so changing the ID won't work.

Comment: Don: yeah forgot about the singleton aspect. Basically you want a singleton that doesn't have the size cached is that right? About the upgrade, what I've done is updated the ID to something different for the new version. E.g. docWindow for v1, then docWindowv2 for v2 etc.